# creating a random list of coins from a repository

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to build a simple app that would display a coin collection for each user I type into a textfield. The coin collection would have to be unique to each user. I already have the repository for the coins. How do I generate a new random coin collection for each user? Each collection could have multiple coins of the same value but with different years.

```
object CoinRepository {

fun getCoinCollection(): List<Coin> {
    return listOf(
        Coin(
            id = 1,
            name = "Penny",
            year = (1900..2022).random()
        ),
        Coin(
            id = 2,
            name = "Nickel",
            year = (1900..2022).random()
        ),
        Coin(
            id = 3,
            name = "Dime",
            year = (1900..2022).random()
        ),
        Coin(
            id = 4,
            name = "Quarter",
            year = (1900..2022).random()
        ),
        Coin(
            id = 5,
            name = "Dollar",
            year = (1900..2022).random()
        )
    )
}
```

}

```
data class Coin(
val id: Int,
val name: String,
val year: Int
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import kotlin.random.Random

// Define your specific data in an enum, with all the relevant properties
enum class Denomination(val id: Int, val label: String) {
    PENNY(1, "Penny"),
    NICKEL(2, "Nickel"),
    DIME(3, "Dime"),
    QUARTER(4, "Quarter"),
    DOLLAR(5, "Dollar");
    
    companion object {
        // a simple way to return one of the instances at random - the property
        // avoids creating a new values() array every time it's called
        val values = values()
        fun random() = values.random()
    }
}

// a basic way to keep the random date logic in the Coin class itself, using
// a default parameter. No validation involved obviously!
data class Coin(val id: Int, val label: String, val year: Int = (1900..2022).random())

// get a random number of Coins, within a certain min/max
fun getCoinCollection() = List(Random.nextInt(1, 10)) {
    // pulls a random coin type and creates a Coin, letting its constructor
    // handle the random date (you could do it here if you want)
    Denomination.random().run { Coin(id, label) }
}
```

There's more than one way to organise it, I've thrown a few things in there so you can get some ideas of how you might do it. But it's basically a function that creates a list of random length (within limits), and then creates a `Coin` for each item, using a random `Denomination`

The `Denomination` enum is just a way to define your data, a fixed set of possible items with certain properties. Because enums generate that `values()` array automatically (containing all its instances) you can easily pick one at random. You could also extend the properties here to include a valid date range for each coin type, etc

You *could* just automatically generate the `label` and `id` values from the enum's `name` and `ordinal` properties (e.g. `"PENNY"` and `0`) so you don't need to declare them explicitly - I feel like it's usually a good idea to decouple the data from how it's represented in the enum in code, but that's your call - I've included it so you can see how

Comment: Thank you very much that worked perfectly.